# diccionarios en diccionario, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, funciones, programación-funcional

Tengo un diccionario con listas:

```
d1 = {
  'Carlos': {
     'manzanas': ['12', 'verdes', '7', 'rojas', '5'],
      'uvas': ['8', 'negras', '5', 'verdes', '3']
   },
   'Juan': {
      'manzanas': ['7', 'verdes', '5', 'rojas', '2'],
      'uvas': ['9', 'negras', '9'], 'pomelo': ['12', 'amarillo', '5', 'rosado', '7'] 
   },
   'Pedro': {
      'manzanas': ['14', 'verdes',' 6', ' rojas', ' 8'], 'pomelo': ['19', 'amarillo', '10', 'rosado', '9'] 
   }
}
```

Quisiera hacer una función donde ingrese una fruta y me muestre SOLO quien tiene mas cantidad de la misma(la cantidad es el primer numero de la lista de cada fruta), tambien los tipos de esa fruta y su cantidad respectiva.

**Detalle: d1 esta cargado desde un archivo.csv en mi PC. La funcion me deberia servir para cualquier otro archivo.csv(del mismo formato) que abra en el Python. El programa para abrir el archivo y colocarlo en d1 ya esta hecho.

Comment: Saludos Jarni, por curiosidad, ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: Esta no es una pagina de peticiones, no trabajamos para ti. Muéstranos el código que has probado y podemos encaminarte en la dirección adecuada o solucionar algún bug que tengas.

Answer (score 1):

He usado burbuja pero creo que esto es lo que estas buscando:

```
def quien_tien_mas(fruta):
  mayor = 0
  quien = None
  for persona in d1:
    if fruta in d1[persona] and len(d1[persona][fruta]) > 0 and int(d1[persona][fruta][0]) > mayor:
      mayor = int(d1[persona][fruta][0])
      quien = persona
  return quien, mayor
```